# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for <Service>

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This error prevents my app from loading due to a Modal Service

followed this [post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19417)

app.module

```
import { ModalService } from './Services/Modal/modal.service';

providers: [
...,
ModalService,
...
]
```

modal.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ProfileComponent } from '..';
import { ChatComponent} from '..';
import { Contact } from '../../../Schemas/Contact';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

  constructor(
    private modalCtrl: ModalController    
  ) { }

  public async openChat(contact: Contact) {
    const chat = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: ChatComponent,
      componentProps: {contact}
    });
    return await chat.present();
  }

  public async openProfileComponent(info: Info) {
    const profileComponent = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: ProfileComponent,
      componentProps: {info}
    });
    return await profileComponent.present();
  }

  public dismiss() {
    return this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

the page that has the issue:

```
import { ModalService } from 'src/app/Services/Modal/modal.service';

export class ChatComponent {
  constructor(
    ...
    public modalService: ModalService,
    ) {}

 public async openProfile() {
    this.modalService.openProfileComponent(this.info);
 }
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening as there are other Pages that are using this service as well and there is no problem with it. I have tried comparing and seeing what is different but I am unable to see why it's unable to resolve the parameter.

I know I have a circular dependency, that I will address once it is loading on my device. But, it can't resolve it and I have no idea

```
-entryComponent -(click)-> chatComponent
                           |-(click)->profileComponent
```

Comment: Did you include IonicModule?

Comment: You are dynamically generating the ProfileComponent in ModelService, so you need to add `ProfileComponent` in `entryComponents` sections of AppModule, please check this if this works

Comment: @Ankit I have updated my AppModule and included the two dynamically loaded Components as entry components, but, still the same issue.

Comment: @TheUnreal yes I did

Comment: the reason I am getting this is because of circular dependency. Once I have that figured out I will be sure to post an answer

Answer (score 0):

can't make an ionic 4 modal controller without circle dependency error so scrapping it.